# Is there a way to automate login without email verification in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, cypress

I am new to cypress and am writing tests to login to the application. but i have 1 issue with automating the login system, it keeps asking me the verification code sent to my email, how do i bypass it in cypress?

it keeps asking me the verification code sent to my email, how do i bypass it in cypress?

Comment: What auth system are you using? Cypress has a general guide for using login -> https://docs.cypress.io/guides/end-to-end-testing/testing-your-app#Logging-in , but also they have more specific guide for different auths.

Comment: i use just username and password

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: so when i use username and password login in cypress, a verification number is sent to my email. and i have to enter this verification number to the input field in cypress. since cypress does not have access to my email account, i can not enter the verification number to the application i am trying to login. how do i bypass this verification in cypress? may be i can do once and next time i login cypress somehow recognize me.

Answer (score 1):

Actually removing the step entirely is unlikely to be possible (as it's probably deeply woven into your product's logic) and it's definely unadvisable from a security standpoint as any workarounds or backdoors into authentication logic are generally a bad idea.

Even then, it's really important to note that removing that step entirely means that you have no coverage of that logic itself (meaning that if there is a bug introduced in the email, such as the logic that creates those 'auth codes',  you'll never know about it).

Full disclosure I work for Mailosaur, but regardless of the tool you use I would recommend using an email testing tool like this for this kind of workflow (its how we test our own product).

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to include extra Cypress steps for opening your e-mail webclient and still stick to genuine flow of application- think about getting this verification number by REST request (e.g. Mailosaur has this functionality). Please write if it answers your need.